# Is there a way to add a ultrasonic sensor on the ev3 COR3 robot?

Tags: ev3, robotic, sensor-ultrasonic

When I built the COR3 robot I started to have some fun programming it. But then I wanted to add a ultrasonic sensor on my robot but I can't seem to find a way to place it on my robot. If you can please help me where to put it I will attach a photo to show you more information and a link.

https://ev3lessons.com/RobotDesigns/instructions/COR3.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultrasonic sensor is useful for navigation.  This robot design has a nice skirt and positioning the ultrasonic sensor should not interfere with that skirt.  Also the ultrasonic sensor is excellent at detecting right angles like the floor meeting a wall.  So, I'd recommend positioning the sensor on either a side (for following along a wall) or the back (to slow down just before reaching a wall when backing up).  It doesn't matter a lot whether the sensor is mounted vertically or horizontally.

So, given all that how do you mount it on the robot?  Pins and a couple beams or right angle beams.  You might also find an existing small pin that can be replaced with a deeper pin.  Maybe the better answer is lots of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have been waiting for someone to reply to me but I had patience. Thank you for giving me an idea to where I should put it now.